# Translation for "People - Place - Time" for a slogan in a business context

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, sinónimos, hispanoamérica

How would you translate `PEOPLE - PLACE - TIME` in Spanish but in a business context?

I know that PEOPLE = GENTE, PLACE = LUGAR/ESPACIO, TIME = TIEMPO. However, I want synonyms for this in a business context to write it in a business document for Latin American people. I am looking for something catchy and impacting.

Comment: If you could use them in a sentence in English to give more context or an example of usage it would help to get better answers.

Comment: They won't be used in sentence or paragraph nor context. It's a slogan! COMPANY NAME second line PEOPLE - PLACE - TIME. I was thinking on PERSONAS/GENTE - LUGAR - TIEMPO.

Comment: Usually, slogans are a synthetic construct of broad but significant concepts. Which are those concepts behind the slogan you would like to translate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would favor `asistentes` or even `audiencia` over "gente" for `people`. Without more context is difficult to give you a better word, since it's impossible to know for sure what you really want to convey. If you are going to use it as a slogan `personas` should convey more than `gente` that you are trying to create meaningful links with people.

For `place` I would rather use `lugar`, which sound pretty generic and neutral rather than `espacio`. You could say that barely anything is a `lugar` but you won't describe everything as a `espacio`. A room in a building or even some place outdoors can be considered `lugar`, but I would be less prone describe them as `espacios`.

For `time` don't use `tiempo`. Could be the most accurate translation, but you would be better off using "fecha/hora". I understand that this is more like "date", but if you want to tell people when something is going to happen don't use `tiempo`. Use `duración` if you are referring to the length in time of the event and "fecha/hora`for the date-time.`Tiempo` used just like that, does not recall "when something is going to happen".

Comment: I'm not very sure about audiencia. It's like a slogan something that tend to be used as a moto for the company! This words are not in a specific context or paragraph. There are isolated to represent in general terms PERSONAS - LUGAR - TIEMPO. But I'm looking for something impacting! Or as I did, it's ok for you? GENTE / PERSONAS not sure

Comment: If you are using it as a slogan, "personas" is better than "gente", and I would leave then "tiempo" as it is, but that does not mean that is necessarily evocative for me.